# *Solved* IONIC 5 HTTP GET ERROR. Unable to make http get request due to 401 error

Tags: http, ionic-framework, jwt

I am using IONIC 5 and I'm following the tutorial.

https://devdactic.com/jwt-authentication-ionic/

Everything works except for

```
  getSpecialData() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/api/special`).pipe(
      catchError(e => {
        let status = e.status;
        if (status === 401) {
          this.showAlert('You are not authorized for this!');
          this.logout();
        }
        throw new Error(e);
      })
    )
  }
```

I'm getting 401 error which is unauthorized. Namely I think it is because of the header wasn't included in the http get. But why the tutorial is working and mine's not ? How do I add the header to the HTTP GET REQUEST ? I've been searching and tested various recommendation online. Couldn't get it working. This is my current code. Still not working. Getting 401 error.

```
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization' : 'Bearer' + this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY)});
  return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/special', {headers: headers}).pipe (
    catchError(e => {
      let status = e.status;
      if (status === 401) {
        this.showAlert('You are not authorized');
        this.logout();
      }
      throw new Error(e);
    })  
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Use Flask-JWT-Extended.